# Difference between Excel 2010 VBA DB2 functionality and Access 2007 DB2 functionality?

Tags: ms-access, excel, db2, subquery, vba

SOLUTION:

It turns out that I was merely using the wrong criteria in my WHERE condition. There are many variations of the LOCATION I am trying to exclude, and I did not see the difference. Thanks to Remou for helping me out in chat!

PROBLEM:

I have an Access 2007 instance that contains a DB2 linked table. I also have an Excel 2010 VBA script that access that same DB2 table.

From this DB2 table, I am selecting a userID, location, reporting manager ID and reporting manager location. The first 3 fields are directly stored, whereas reporting manager location can only be derived through a subquery linking userID and reporting manager id, and getting the location for reporting manager id.

This query gives me exactly what I wanted ->

```
SELECT DISTINCT main.USERID, main.LOCATION, main.REPORT_MGR_USERID,  manager_data.LOCATION 
    FROM employee_table main
    INNER JOIN employee_table manager_data
    ON main.REPORT_MGR_USERID=manager_data.USERID
```

However, I discovered certain locations that I do not want to show in the results. So I developed this query ->

```
SELECT DISTINCT main.USERID, main.LOCATION, main.REPORT_MGR_USERID,  manager_data.LOCATION 
FROM employee_table main
INNER JOIN employee_table manager_data
    ON main.REPORT_MGR_USERID=manager_data.USERID
WHERE main.LOCATION NOT IN ('location one', 'location two')
```

The only difference is this ->

```
WHERE main.LOCATION NOT IN ('location one', 'location two')
```

This works as expected when running in the Access 2007 instance, but does not work in the Excel VBA instance (where I actually need it). I have verified that the query string is exactly the same.

What would make this work differently between Access and Excel?

EDIT:

Here is how I am executing in Excel ->

```
sqlString = "SELECT DISTINCT main.USERID, main.LOCATION, main.REPORT_MGR_USERID,  manager_data.LOCATION " _
                & "FROM employee_table main " _
                & "INNER JOIN employee_table manager_data " _
                & "ON main.REPORT_MGR_USERID=manager_data.USERID   " _
                & "WHERE main.LOCATION NOT IN ('location one', 'location two')"

sConnection = "Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" & connectingUserID & ";Password=" & connectingPassword & ";Data Source=EmployeeInfoDB;Mode=Read"

Set adoConnection = New ADODB.Connection

Set nameRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset

adoConnection.Open sConnection

nameRecordSet.Open Source:=sqlString, ActiveConnection:=adoConnection
```

Comment: Capitalization. As far as I recall, Excel is case sensitive.

Comment: @Remou do you mean in the 'NOT IN ('location one')' section? Everything is the same between my query, and what is in the DB.

Comment: Yes, I know that `A` is not equal to `a` in Excel. I have not tested whether `A` is `IN ("a")` There is also a problem with blanks/nulls, I think.

Comment: The second query includes some single quotes, while the first does not.  This makes me suspicious that it is a string quoting issue in Excel VBA.  If it is not something simple like that, you'll need to show your code and tell us the exact error message.

Comment: I tested and capitalization is not it. As an aside, a very simple query using NOT IN worked as expected in Excel, with single quotes.

Comment: What is your connection string? Have you got mixed data types?

Comment: Note also that `NOT IN ('a')` will not return nulls.

Comment: @Remou I have updated with my Excel code.

Comment: @dan1111 It does not error out. It just returns the data that I am trying to exclude, as if the WHERE condition were not there.

Comment: I have tried several tests but I get the right answer each time, even connecting to SQL Server through Excel and Access. I wonder if it is to do with the way DB2 works? Have you tried `WHERE location = 'location two'`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17455/discussion-between-remou-and-hacket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

It turns out that I was merely using the wrong criteria in my WHERE condition. There are many variations of the LOCATION I am trying to exclude, and I did not see the difference. Thanks to Remou for helping me out in chat!